# Can't set styles to elements with a specified class javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('loader').style.opacity = "0";
```

this code will give an error in my console displayed below:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByClassName('loader').style.opacity = "0"')
```

I have already tried these, but these also do not work:

```
document.document.querySelectorAll('.loader').style.opacity = '0';
document.document.querySelector('.loader').style.opacity = '0';
```

My html code:

```
<div class="loader">Some Text</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return an HTML Collection. If you only have one `loader` div, then you could do `getElementsByClassName('loader')[0]`

Comment: `document.querySelector('.loader').style.opacity = '0';` should work if you're really got at least one element in the DOM with that class.

Answer (score 1):

The `.getElementsByClassName()` function returns a **list** of elements.  You have to iterate over that list with your own code.

```
var loaders = document.getElementsByClassName('loader');
for (var i = 0; i < loaders.length; ++i)
  loaders[i].style.opacity = '0';
```

If you just want to operate on particular members of the list, you can (if you're careful) treat it like an array.  I mention being careful because `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a "live" NodeList. If you remove the class "loader" from one or more of the elements, the list will change. (That's not the case for the lists returned from `.querySelectorAll()`.)

Comment: How can I select the first and second one?

Comment: By their index? checking that they exist of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you select elements by classes you most will most likely end up with an array of elements. You need to set the parameters for each one. Pure JS doesn't behave as jQuery regarding this.

First make your selection by

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('loader');
```

then cycle through them

```
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].style.opacity = "0";
}
```

See if this helps..